# I am trying to find an open ball such that $p\in$ B for all $x \in$ B we have $f(x)>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

The question is as follows: 
Let $f:\mathbb{R}$$^n$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be continuous at the point $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $f(p)>0$. Show that there is an open ball $B \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ such that $p \in B$ and for all $x \in B$ we have $f(x)>0$.

Solution: I am assuming that we need to look locally and use the definition of the open to prove this fact. My current issue is that I am still unsure of what I need to do exactly. I am still relatively new to optimization theory and as such any guidance or “push in the right direction” would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: note: I have made some edits and renamed some things to make the post sensible which I believe is what OP wanted to ask.

Comment: In general, questions about sets ≠ set theory.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, try putting $\epsilon = f(p)$ and use triangle inequality.
(If you are using the open-set definition of continuity, consider the open set $(0, 2f(p))$ and look at its preimage.)

---

**EDIT:** Some more elaboration.
Consider the open subset $U = (0, 2f(p))$ of $\Bbb R$.
Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. (Why? By definition.)
Note that $p \in f^{-1}(U).$ (Why?)
Thus, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(p, \epsilon) \subset U$. (Why?)

Moreover, for any $x \in B(p, \epsilon)$, we have $f(x) > 0$. (Why?)

Comment: If you are using the open set definition, you would've seen something like "$f^{-1}(U)$ is open if $U$ is open". The set $f^{-1}(U)$ is the pre-image of the set $U$ (under the function $f$).

Comment: I see... so my lecture notes are telling me that I should start with the open set definition and assume that if if the preimage is open then U is also open. Should I then use the idea that for some $\epsilon$ >0, B(f(x), $\epsilon$) = U =open?

Comment: More importantly, can I just assume that the preimage is open, or no?

Comment: "if the preimage is open then U is also open". I think you've read it wrong. Continuity does **not** mean that "$f^{-1}(U)$ open $\implies$ $U$ open". Only the converse is necessarily true. (For example, consider $f(x) = x^2$ and the set $U = [0, 1)$, its preimage is open but it is not.) Moreover, even if $U$ is open, it does not mean that it equals $B(f(x), \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$. However, what you *can* conclude it that it *contains* $B(f(x), \epsilon)$ (for some $\epsilon$). (And that will be sufficient for this problem.)

Comment: I have added some more details to my answer now.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I will try and analyze this answer and try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $B$ such that $|f(x)-f(p)| <\frac {f(p)} 2$ for all $x \in B$. (This is possible by continuity). Then $f(x) \geq f(p)-|f(x)-f(p)| >f(p)-\frac {f(p)} 2=\frac {f(p)} 2$ for all $x \in B$.

(The first inequality comes from the fact that $f(p)-f(x) \leq |f(x)-f(p)|$)

Existence of the open ball is in the first sentence of my answer:
 It is a consequence of the definition of continuity where I take $\epsilon =\frac {f(p)} 2$. If you want to use inverse images of open sets consider $f^{-1} (f(p)-\frac {f(p)} 2, f(p)+\frac {f(p)} 2)$. This is open and it it contains $f(p)$ so there is some open ball $B$ around $p$ contained in this open set.

Comment: Right, but how does this prove an open ball is subseteq of R exists?

Comment: @Tony456 Exisetnce of the open ball is in the first sentence of my answer. It is a conseqeunce of the definition of continuity where I take $\epsilon =\frac {f(p)} 2$. If you want to use inverse images of open sets consider $f^{-1} (f(p)-\frac {f(p)} 2, f(p)+\frac {f(p)} 2)$. This is open and it it contains $p$ so there is some open ball $B$ around $p$ contained in this open set.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but I am still confused on how we confirm f^(-1)(....) is actually open. My concern here is that I am  clueless on inverse images.